# org-mode caption html export cramped

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

If you start a blank org buffer and put in

```
#+CAPTION: This is the caption for the next table (or link)
| ... | ... |
|-----+-----|
```

then html-export it, it comes out all cramped and vertical.

```
Table 1: 
This is
the caption
for the
...
```

In my Chrome Inspect I see *user agent stylesheet* entries

```
user agent stylesheet entries
caption {
    display: table-caption;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}

Inherited from table
user agent stylesheet
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    text-indent: initial;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

This however in the same bare-bones file

```
#+caption: Y approaches infinity as X approaches 0 from either side
#+RESULTS:
[[file:images/oneoverx1.svg]]
```

behaves okay, i.e., it simply puts the caption text (with a figure #) in a `<p>...</p>` and displays it under the image.

Not sure how this cramped outcome can be corrected -- or what the difference in these two uses of caption is. Something in org-mode export is doing this no doubt. Same in Firefox, BTW. On 9.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the caption is determined by the width of the table. Make the table wider and the caption will be wider:

```org
#+CAPTION: This is the caption for the next table (or link)
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 500
| a | b |
|---+---|
| c | d |
| e | f |
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks again. Now, can only tables and image (links) have captions? It seems a code block, latex math, etc. can't have a caption, at least as I've tested. Even though the docs say they can. It says: `...caption mechanism can apply to many others—e.g., LaTeX equations, source code blocks. Depending on the export back-end, those may or may not be handled.` What sort of "export back-end" do I need?

Comment: Based on what you quote: "Depending on the export back-end, those may or may not be handled."  I read this to mean that the info channel of the exporter contains all the caption information: whether the exporter makes any use of it is up to each individual exporter. E.g. the HTML exporter provides caption handling for source blocks: see the function `org-html-src-block`; other exporters might not. However, you should create a separate question for such concerns: it is outside the scope of the current question.